# NEO4J Query to exclude some nodes

Tags: neo4j

With a data model that looks similar to this:

```
(u:User)-[:POSTED]->(p:Post {created_at: 123)-[:ABOUT]->(t:Topic {name: "Blue")
```

What is the best way to find distinct count of users who posted/created a post with {created_at: 123} AND also don't have a post with {created_at: 124} about topic "Blue".

Closest I can get is to collect ids and then exclude them but that doesn't scale when you have a lot of nodes (millions).

[EDITED]

I also need the `created_at` times to be specifiable as ranges.

Comment: Is the `Post.created_at` field indexed? What about `Topic.name`?

Comment: Yes both are indexed.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the requirement that the times be specifiable as ranges, as indicated in a comment to @InversionFalcon's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query allows you to specify `created_at` ranges. In this example, the *desirable* range is [123..130], and the *undesirable* "Blue" range is [131..140]. In your actual query, the range endpoints should be specified by [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters).

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:POSTED]->(p1:Post)
WHERE 123 <= p1.created_at <= 130
WITH user
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:POSTED]->(p2:Post)-[:ABOUT]->(:Topic{name:"Blue"})
WHERE 131 <= p2.created_at <= 140
WITH user, p2
WHERE p2 IS NULL
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS userCount;
```

The `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause is there to match the *undesirable* "Blue" paths, and the `WHERE p2 IS NULL` clause will filter out `user` nodes that have any such paths.

Comment: You can also define ranges with chained inequalities, which simplifies those where clauses a bit. `WHERE 123 <= p1.created_at <= 130`

Comment: @InverseFalcon: That is cool. I have never seen that usage before. My answer has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an index on `Post.created_at` and `Topic.name` (for speed), this should work:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:POSTED|CREATED]->(:Post{created_at:123})
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( (user)-[:POSTED|CREATED]->(:Post{created_at:124})-[:ABOUT]->(:Topic{name:"Blue"}) )
RETURN count(DISTINCT user) as userCount
```

It's worth profiling that query, and if it isn't using the created_at and name indexes, supply that to the query with `USING INDEX` after your `MATCH`.

Comment: is there a way to use ranges in both external and internal parts in place of 123 and 124? Ex. ..{created_at: [123..130]} or do I have to use WHERE for that? Is it possible to put WHERE clause inside WHERE NOT EXISTS (..) block?

Comment: You'll want to use cybersam's answer for the ranges. And for EXISTS() and NOT EXISTS() blocks more complicated predicates are hard to process, as you typically need a variable for those predicates, but you can't define new variables within the EXISTS() blocks. cybersam's optional matching where the optional match is null is the best workaround, but it really calls for a better solution, such as an [EXCLUDE MATCH](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7762) clause.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation